# Transformer control using a MCU

Tags: transformer

I am trying to generate 12V output using this transformer. From the datasheet it states that Vin can be 20-48V at 150kHz. Now, I am trying to send a pwm to a MOSFET that will control the connection to the transformer. Is it possible ? Also, what is the duty cycle that I need to supply ?

[image: Transformer]

[Datasheet](http://katalog.we-online.com/pbs/datasheet/750311590.pdf)

[image: Schematic]

The schematic is the one I wish to implement. So, my doubt is pertaining to the PWM duty cycle.

Comment: Within a few cycles of MOSFET switching, this circuit WILL cause the transformer to saturate and smoke will appear. Please try and explain what you want.

Comment: @Andyaka. I am trying to merely implement whats shown in the transformer datasheet. It shows a specific Vin and switching rate. Or is it not that straighforward ?

Comment: Changing the schematic has invalidated part of my question - please don't do this because it just means more work for me and when I edit it bumps this question to the top of the freaking question list and folk can get upset.

Comment: my sincere apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS ANSWER WAS GIVEN BEFORE THE QUESTION SCHEMATIC WAS ALTERED.

> I am trying to merely implement whats shown in the transformer
>   datasheet. It shows a specific Vin and switching rate. Or is it not
>   that straighforward ?

It's not quite that straightforward.

If you are wanting to use it as a fly-back transformer then your dot notation is likely wrong and you will need a snubber circuit on your primary: -

[image]

If you are wanting to use it as a forward converting transformer you will need a reset winding or a push pull drive. [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLzqLhz_7KAhXJmBoKHeT_B7gQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onsemi.com%2Fpub%2FCollateral%2FAND8039-D.PDF&usg=AFQjCNGPtUWf3mQJVRCeD4K9PmoOwf4Agg) is a good article that shows a single transistor forward converter - note the reset winding to prevent magnetic saturation. Here's a similar schematic: -

[image]

Note that N3 and D3 form the reset circuit. Below is a two transistor forward converter: -

[image]

> So, my doubt is pertaining to the PWM duty cycle.

Get the topology right first then use a simulator like LTSpice.

Comment: I am trying to do a flyback using this transformer. I have shorted 1 and 2 and connected it to Vcc(20-48V). And shorted 3 and 4 and connected to GND. 5 and 4 I have not connected to anything. In the secondary I have connected(shortyed) 10,11 and 12 which makes up the output Vcc. The 7,8 and 9 mare shorted to make output GND. 


You have shorted 5 and 4 and likewise 6 and 7. So, how can there be any isolation here ?

Comment: Yes, my dot notations are wrong. Sincere apologies. I do have a snubber across the primary.
Assuming a right topology what would be the dutycycle ?~

Comment: Current limiting would limit the number of FETs that you will blow

Comment: @Board-Man why not show the circuit, after all you have already changed it. Also I don't understand your point about isolation.